# Problems with roles in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

Please note: I am pretty new to laravel and programming in general.

So I am working on setting up a role system on my laravel project and I followed a tutorial and did eveything the same.
My problem is that when registering it should register a new user with role 'User' and that's not happening. Also my database seeding isn't saving any role ID to my users.

**My users table migration:**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('roles_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**My roles table migration:**

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

**My role_user table migration:**

```
class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

**My DataBaseSeeder:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Role comes before User seeder here.
        $this->call(RoleTableSeeder::class);
        // User seeder will use the roles above created.
        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

**RoleTableSeeder**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Role;

class RoleTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $role_worker = new Role();
        $role_worker->name = 'worker';
        $role_worker->save();

        $role_admin = new Role();
        $role_admin->name = 'admin';
        $role_admin->save();

        $role_user = new Role();
        $role_user->name = 'user';
        $role_user->save();
    }
}
```

**UserTableSeeder**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Role;
use App\User;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $role_worker = Role::where('name', 'worker')->first();
        $role_admin  = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
        $role_user  = Role::where('name', 'user')->first();

        $worker = new User();
        $worker->name = 'Worker User';
        $worker->email = 'worker@worker.com';
        $worker->password = Hash::make('password');
        $worker->save();
        $worker->roles()->attach($role_worker);

        $admin = new User();
        $admin->name = 'Admin user';
        $admin->email = 'admin@admin.com';
        $admin->password = Hash::make('password');
        $admin->save();
        $admin->roles()->attach($role_admin);

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = 'Regular user';
        $user->email = 'user@user.com';
        $user->password = Hash::make('password');
        $user->save();
        $user->roles()->attach($role_user);
    }
}
```

**Tables after migrating/seeding**

- [roles table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p26Lg.png)
- [role_user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZGj7.png)
- [users_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8wtd.png)

So again, my problem is that when registering it should register a new user with role 'User' and that's not happening. Also my database seeding isn't saving any roles_id to my users.

Comment: Do you have the relationships setup on the models themselves?

Comment: @AlecJoy Based on the screenshots, yes, they are, as `$user->roles()->attach()` would fail miserable if they weren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pivot relationship; there is no need to put the `roles_id` column on your users. Drop these lines from your migration:

`CreateUsersTable`

```
// $table->unsignedBigInteger('roles_id')->nullable();
// $table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
```

Everything else looks good; your `roles` and `users` tables are being populated, and the pivot is setting the correct values for `user_id` and `role_id`. Now, you'd access the user's roles via

```
$user->roles
// Should return a `Collection` of roles, based on the number of records in `role_user`
```

As a sidenote, you generally don't have an auto-incrementing id on a `pivot` table, since the data is constantly changing, and you're unlikely to reference `role_user.id` at any point, so you can also drop this line:

`CreateRoleUserTable`

```
// $table->bigIncrements('id');
```

Edit: The bigger issue here is a fundamental lack of understanding on how `pivot` and `many-to-many` relationships work (and that's ok, you said you're new to Laravel and programming).

I believe you're trying to set `roles_id` on `users` to `role_user.id`, but that's fundamentally incorrect. That is not how this type of relationship works. It uses an intermediate table `role_user`, which has `user_id` and `role_id` to link many instances of `users` to many instances of `roles`.

If you were to set `roles_id` on `users`, you could only ever have a single `role`, at which point this would cease to be a `many-to-many`, and would be a simple link between `users` and `roles`, which would render the `role_user` table completely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your very indebt answer! You are right, I lack a fundemantal understanding about pivot and many-to-many relationships, this concept is new to me.

Comment: No problem! And again, I hope that didn't come across as mean; I didn't mean it as a negative thing; everyone struggles with new concepts at first. You'll pick up the skills eventually, and you were actually quite close in this initial attempt. Keep up the good work!

Comment: You didn't come across as mean, I very much appreciate your feedback thanks!